# What will happen if we cut a bar magnet diagonally?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

What will happen to the magnetic field and pole strength if we cut a bar magnet diagonally? Since shape of north pole and south pole became different, does this affects the pole strength?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cutting you can just add a wedge shaped iron at one pole, the strength per $\mathrm{mm^2}$ will go down, but not the total strength.

Answer (score 0):

This would change the amount of magnetic field from each of the smaller magnets that is created. Since there is less magnetic material generating each magnetic field the strength of those fields would be smaller. This would also make the force from the smaller magnets smaller as well.